# How to solve sessionnotcreated issue in Selenium webdriver for Chrome browser?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch Chrome browser but getting an error of "session not created" in Selenium. It research on it and I found if the browser and Chrome driver is not compatible then we will get such issue, so download the latest version of Chrome Driver i.e. Chrome Driver 2.45 which is compatible with v70-72.

So I have downloaded browser version 70.0.3538.67, but still I am unable to launch the Chrome browser and getting the same error. I am using Eclipse 2018-09 and selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59. Below is my code and error message:

Code:-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class open_browser {
public WebDriver driver;
public void aa1() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Selenium 
files\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("google.com");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
open_browser ob=new open_browser();
ob.aa1();
}

}
```

Error message:-

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615291 
>   (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387) 
>      on port 48165
>      Only local connections are allowed.
>     Exception in thread "main" >org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
>     session not created
>       from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
>       (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.67)
>       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 
>       (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 
>       x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 3.56 seconds
>       Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 
>       17:32:46'
>       System info: host: 'aspirehp-PC', ip: '192.168.43.104', os.name: 'Windows 
>       7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:159)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
>       at practise.open_browser.aa1(open_browser.java:10)
>       at practise.open_browser.main(open_browser.java:17)

Comment: also using selenium-java-2.53.1. i guess it is a configuration error so i have given all the version i am using. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go for all latest one's.

1. Latest chrome browser (as admin to system, generally install in C:\Program Files (x86))
2. Latest chromedriver http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads presently ChromeDriver 2.45
3. Latest webdriver https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ presently 3.141.59

Also update the get, need to provide complete URL , like

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\workspace\\Training\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your respond, I tried all the latest version and above i also have given the error message where you can see the versions i am using, still i download all the latest version again and tried but facing the same issue. i am still getting the same error message.

Comment: is chrome installed location is in c:\program file? and used complete url?